# Create SCCM 2012 task sequence to install package ONLY on log off

Tags: sccm

I want to create an SCCM 2012 task sequence to install a package ONLY on log off, what is the best way to go about doing this in the Task Sequence?

As always thanks,
Rico

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Personally I'd use the task sequence to create a scheduled task which runs on logoff. Of course the downside to this is that you can't (easily) get the return code from the installer to determine if it succeeded or not.

I'm curious as to why you need it to run on log off exactly? If we knew that we may be able to provide better alternatives.

Comment: Hello Matt!  Thank you for the information, so how would I incorporate the launch of the installer (package) in the scheduled task?  and the details are, we need to reinstall a newer version of an application which has some bug fixes in it, which requires a reboot, but we dont want to interrupt the users.  So saying that, I guess we could do it on login as well.

Comment: I'd probably look into the reboot requirement first. Is it because the software is running, or has a service? If so can you stop it beforehand and avoid the reboot?

Comment: It is a requirement, trust me, I have confirmed.

Comment: Ok, I've seen a few of those before. I've always tried to avoid log-off tasks, as they have a chance of failure if Windows decides to timeout during the logout/shutdown process. In this instance, I'd be tempted to set the software to install only if no user is logged in, and then schedule it for overnight. Obviously this is no good for users who don't log out though...